# Dynamically adding class instance to Python instance à la __setattr__

Tags: python, oop

Suppose I have two Python classes, A and B. I would like to be able to do the following:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.a.attr1 = 'foo'
>>> b.a.attr2 = 'bar'
```

where 'a' is an instance of A. I can't use `__setattr__` as I would if 'a' was some
"primitive" type. Is there some elegant way to accomplish this, other than

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.a = A()
>>> b.a.attr1 = 'foo'
>>> b.a.attr2 = 'bar'
```

?

Comment: Why not to put `self.a = A()` into `B.__init__` method?

Comment: I should have mentioned... I can't do that because many of the classes I would unconditionally instantiate in `__init__` (potentially) won't be used. Also, some code in A() may fire at `__init__` time that I won't necessarily be ready for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to either create `a` in the `__init__` of `B`, use a [`__getattr__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to create `a` dynamically, or use a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

`__init__` approach:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
```

`__getattr__` approach:

```
class B(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'a':
            self.a = A()
            return self.a
        raise AttributeError(attr)
```

Property approach:

```
class B(object):
    _a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        if self._a is None:
            self._a = A()
        return self._a
```

Of course, the property and `__getattr__` approaches do not *have* to store the `A()` instance on `self`, it could just return a pre-existing `A()` instance from somewhere else instead.

Comment: HA!! Your `__getattr__` approach does exactly what I'm looking for. I wouldn't have thought to use `__GETattr__`, as I'm setting an attribute with `b.a.attr1='foo'` `__init__` is not an option for me because I don't want to instantiate a bunch of classes that I won't potentially be using. I should have mentioned that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(object):
    pass

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

b = B()
b.a.attr1 = 'foo'
b.a.attr2 = 'bar'
```